# Adding $i of a FOR loop into a JSON key value

Tags: json, linux, bash, rest

i am looking for a way to add an array variable into a JSON key value.

A part of a JSON that doesn't work looks like this:

```
"target":["some/dir/'$i'"]
```

A FOR loop is:

```
for i in ${ARRAY[*]}
do
    cURL -k -v -H 'Content-type: application/json' -d '{"id":1,"method":"exec","params":[{"data":{"action":"get","resource":"/api/v2/monitor/XXX/XXX/XXX","target":["some/dir/'$i'"]},"url":"XXX"}],"session":"SESSION_KEY",}'
done
```

But instead of getting the value of $i from the array, the $i value comes empty:

```
"target":["some/dir/"]
```

Where is my mistake please?

Comment: Put `declare -p ARRAY` before the loop, and `declare -p i` inside the loop, and see what they say. I see several potential problems having to do with handling of shell and JSON metacharacters, but I don't see anything that'd cause that particular result. What I would suggest immediately: use `for i in "${ARRAY[@]}"` and put double-quotes around `$i`. That'll fix the shell metacharacter problems, but you might still have JSON injection problems. BTW, [shellcheck.net](http://www.shellcheck.net) is good at spotting common shell issues.

Comment: Hah! Right as I submit my comment, @chepner explains how to fix the shell *and* JSON parsing issues. But I'm still not sure that's what's causing the result you're seeing; there may be something else wrong as well.

Comment: BTW, `${ARRAY[*]}` is almost never the right thing -- your array contents are going through string-splitting and globbing. `"${array[@]}"` is better-behaved (the case difference is a matter of [convention](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html), not correctness, but it pains me to write an all-caps shell variable name in something intended to be an example).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `jq` make sure everything is encoded correctly:

```
template='
{
  id: 1, 
  method: "exec",
  params: [
    {
      data: {
        action: "get",  
        resource: "/api/v2/monitor/XXX/XXX/XXX",
        target: ["some/dir/" + $dir]
      },
      url: "XXX"
    }
  ],
  session: "SESSION_KEY"
}
'

for i in "${array[@]}"; do
  data=$(jq -n --arg dir "$i" "$template")
  curl -v -k -H 'Content-type: application/json' -d "$data"
done
```

Comment: unfortunately the environment is restricted, and installing any package on CentOS is impossible.

Comment: Then you should write a small script in, say, Python (which can use `json` from its standard library) to construct the correct payload. Don't trust shell interpolation.